# Passing a unique function as a parameter

Tags: c++, function, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a class that is instantiated with:

`Param::Param(std::function<float()> func)`

which just sets an internal method equal to the passed in method. What I'm confused about is how to actually call something like:

`new Param(std::function<float()>{ return 4.0; });`

I don't want to have to define a function to pass in, can I just pass in a unique function for this?

Comment: What is a "unique function"?

Comment: I don't know what to call it, basically a javascript equivalent would be: `new Param(function(){return 4.0;});`. Just a function that isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: FYI That's usually called an *anonymous* function or lambda function or (technically wrong in many cases, but still common) *closure*.

Comment: An `std::function` can be initialized from a lambda, so yeah, you can pass in a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is anonymous function declaration. This functionality is provided only for C++11. If you are using `g++` compile with `$ g++ -std=g++0x my_file.cpp`

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int call_me(std::function <int(int)> func, int arg = 1)
{
  return func(arg);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

  std::cout << "Default arg: " << call_me([](int v){return v*2;}) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Passing 5: " << call_me([](int v){return v*2;}, 5) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In call_me() declaration we say the first argument is a function receiveing one integer and returnin one integer. Then we declar a default integer argument named arg.

Then we call `call_me()` passing an anonymous function which receives and integer and returns it multiplied by 2 and we don pass an argument. Then we repeat but passing 5 as an argument for the anonymous function.

```
[](int v){return v*2;}
```